# SQLAlchemy: Reflect and Automap Tables with Composite Primary Key

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy, composite-primary-key

I'm trying to reflect and automap some tables in sqlalchemy that have composite primary keys from an Oracle db. When I run

```
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(bind=engine, schema='USER')
Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
Base.prepare()
print(list(Base.classes))
```

I get a list of the tables that have primary keys in the database, and not the ones that don't. I know that you can manually map tables with composite primary keys (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/ormconfiguration.html), but is there a way to feed the two keys that make up the composite primary key to the reflection for automapping?

Comment: I am also keen to know the answer here.

Comment: Now, this composite primary key is supported in Automap Base. I evaluated by print(list(Base.classes)) and it was able to map it.